# CSS Style assignment

Tags: html, css

I have this defined in an existing CSS sheet that I'm working with:

```
label.error-field
```

To assign this to an html element do I simply do `class="error-field"` or do I add the label to have it be `class="label.error-field"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right way:

```
<label class="error-field">My Label</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

`label.error-field` is only applied to `<label>` elements with the class "`error-field`".

So if you want it on a `label`, then you'd just assign the `class` as "`error-field`", like this:

```
<label class="error-field">
```

Answer (score 3):

This will only work on `labels`.

```
<label class="error-field">I'm an error label, yo ho ho</label>
```

The `label.` part is a CSS [type (element) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors) with a [class (`.`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

Answer (score 3):

Add it simply to the label. `class="error-field"`.

Answer (score 3):

`label.error-field` will select an element `label` with a class of `error-field`

```
<label class="error-field">...</label>
```